# iTunes-cover screensaver not showing

Tags: macos, itunes, screensaver

Today I tried to use the iTunes-cover screensaver (for the first time), but my screen (and the preview area in the system preferences) simply stays black, nothing else happens.

Has anybody experienced this too or has an idea what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Restarting iTunes
- Restarting the Mac
- Quitting iTunes and relaunching it while holding down the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key (to designate a different library), then quitting and relaunching it and re-pointing it at your real library
- Selecting a completely different screensaver, then reselecting the iTunes Artwork screensaver.
- Repair disk permissions

Answer (score 0):

Re-creating my iTunes library worked for me.

The procedure consists in moving the *iTunes Music Library.xml* to a different location, removing the *iTunes Library.itl* file and then importing the xml file to re-build the library.

The details are explained in this article on the Apple support site: [iTunes: How to re-create your iTunes library and playlists](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1451?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just that I use iTunes match an none of my music was downloaded local to my computer, simple fix on one of my computers I wanted to save space on my HD so I just downloaded one of my playlists and on another I downloaded the whole library and as soon as it was done it was all there.